# PowerPoint Elapsed Time and remaining time

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on power point slide where i need to show at every slide that how time you have elapsed and how much is remaining from a  30 minute time. request you all please help me to accomplish this task.

Comment: is this for the presenter, or the audience? if it's for the presenter have you considered using 'presentation view' on a second screen?

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to create more advance presentation timing? if yes, how about create a timing system triggered by events such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746741.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745863.aspx ?